# Pandas value_counts() counting same value more than once

Tags: python, pandas, count

I've taken a pandas column called `specialty` that looks like this:

```
0         1,5
1           1
2           1
3           1
4           1
5         1,5
6           3
7           3
8           1
9         1,3
10          1
11    1,2,4,6
12        1,5
13          6
14          3
```

And created a new column that converts values with multiple items to single like so:

```
df['spec_area'] = df['specialty'].replace({
'1,2' : 2,
'1,3' : 3,
'1,4' : 4,
'1,5' : 5,
'1,6' : 6,
'2,6' : 2,
'3,6' : 3,
'1,2,3': 3,
'1,2,6' : 2,
'1,3,6' : 3,
'1,2,3' : 3,
'1,2,4' : 4,
'1,2,4,6' : 4,
'1,2,5' : 5
})
```

And when I run `df['spec_area'].value_counts()` I get:

```
1          211
missing     53
2           42
3           39
5           37
3           34
6           24
4           23
5           23
6           13
4           12
2           11
Name: spec_area, dtype: int64
```

And I don't understand why there are two of every in 2-6.

Comment: Your last and current questions are not really clear. What do you expect? What's wrong with your code?

Comment: I expect the multiple two's, three's etc. to just be counted as one 2, one 3, and those values summed up. I.e. why is `2` appearing twice in `value_counts()`, once as 42 and once as 11. Why not just one `2` with a value count of 53? Is pandas interpreting them as different values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your column is a `string` column and you replace using the dict with a `integer` that is why `value_counts` return two value for number `2` one is a number and other is a string instead of:

```
df['specialty'].replace({
'1,2' : 2,
'1,3' : 3,
'1,4' : 4,
'1,5' : 5,
'1,6' : 6,
'2,6' : 2,
'3,6' : 3,
'1,2,3': 3,
'1,2,6' : 2,
'1,3,6' : 3,
'1,2,3' : 3,
'1,2,4' : 4,
'1,2,4,6' : 4,
'1,2,5' : 5
}
```

do:

```
df['specialty'].replace({
'1,2' : '2',
'1,3' : '3',
'1,4' : '4',
'1,5' : '5',
'1,6' : '6',
'2,6' : '2',
'3,6' : '3',
'1,2,3': '3',
'1,2,6' : '2',
'1,3,6' : '3',
'1,2,3' : '3',
'1,2,4' : '4',
'1,2,4,6' : '4',
'1,2,5' : '5'
}
```

Comment: That does work. The only thing is values that appear by themselves, e.g. just `1` or just `2`, are actually ints. Does that matter?

Comment: Yes, use `df['specialty'].astype(str).replace(...).value_counts()`